# Binding UserControl in XAML

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I am trying to bind a userControl that I create in a class as property.  I couldnt figure out how to show it in XAML.

Example:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public UserControl myUserControl { get; set; };

    public MainWindowViewModel()
        : base()
    {
        _myUserControl = new WelcomePageView());

    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<Window c:Class=".."
   .
   .
   .
 />
<???? {Binding myUserControl}>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding your_usercontrol}" />
```

Comment: This doesnt work , myViewUserControl is not visible. The UserControl trying to add has ViewPort3d element, does it need anything to get visible..

Comment: Ok, shame on me! i just get noticed that width and height values are auto. so they get visibility off. That works.. :)