# Binding XAML usercontrol in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, user-controls, commandparameter

I have two UserControls: **Main** nad **Settings**.
In **Main** in some control I want to set CommandParameter in XAML to **Settings**. In C# code is simple, like:

```
biSettings.CommandParameter = new Settings();
```

How can I do that in XAML?

```
CommandParameter="???"
```

The Settings has own model I'm using MVVM. I found solutions here [Binding UserControl in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299022/binding-usercontrol-in-xaml), but It is not clear MVVM because in VM is MV!
I'm using Silverlight 4.

Comment: which mvvm framework are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Model-View-ViewModel with combination PRISM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the control is a Button, you could so something like this:

```
<Button Command={Binding Foo} Content="Click Me">
  <Button.CommandParameter>
    <mystuff:Settings />
  </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Type type = biSettings.GetType();
  FieldInfo field = type.GetField("CommandParameter");
  if (field != null)
  {
    DependencyProperty dp = (DependencyProperty)field.GetValue(Result);
    if (dp != null)
    {
      ((UserControl)Result).SetValue(dp, YourSettingObject);

    }
  }
```

Comment: I think he said he wants to do it from XAML